# MySQL select with IN (include) and NOT IN (exclude)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a recipe table with recipe numbers and a list of ingredients. I want to select recipe numbers that have (a list of ingredients) AND (do not have another list of ingredients).
Thanks in advance for any direction.

```
CREATE TABLE recipe (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    recipe_num INT,
    ingredient VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO recipe VALUES (1,1,'salt'),(2,1,'pork'),(3,1,'pepper'),(4,1,'milk'),(5,1,'garlic'),
(6,2,'steak'), (7,2,'pepper'),(8,2,'ketchup'),
(9,3,'fish'),(10,3,'lemon'),(11,3,'cheese'),
(12,4,'veal'),(13,4,'cream'),(14,4,'salt'),(15,4,'garlic');


select * from recipe;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | recipe_num | ingredient |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 | salt       |
|  2 |          1 | pork       |
|  3 |          1 | pepper     |
|  4 |          1 | milk       |
|  5 |          1 | garlic     |
|  6 |          2 | steak      |
|  7 |          2 | pepper     |
|  8 |          2 | ketchup    |
|  9 |          3 | fish       |
| 10 |          3 | lemon      |
| 11 |          3 | cheese     |
| 12 |          4 | veal       |
| 13 |          4 | cream      |
| 14 |          4 | salt       |
| 15 |          4 | garlic     |
+----+------------+------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can select all recipe_num that contain meat and dairy. How do I query all recipe_num that contain meat and but not dairy? It seems so easy,

```
SELECT 
    meat.recipe_num, meat.ingredient as meat, dairy.recipe_num, dairy.ingredient as dairy
FROM
    recipe as meat, recipe as dairy
WHERE
    meat.ingredient IN ('pork' , 'steak','chicken','veal')
    AND dairy.ingredient IN ('milk' , 'cheese')
    AND meat.recipe_num = dairy.recipe_num;

+------------+------+------------+-------+
| recipe_num | meat | recipe_num | dairy |
+------------+------+------------+-------+
|          1 | pork |          1 | milk  |
+------------+------+------------+-------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to match the two sub-tables, and then test for `NULL` in the dairy column to find recipes with no match.

```
SELECT DISTINCT meat.recipe_num
FROM recipe AS meat
LEFT JOIN recipe AS dairy 
ON meat.recipe_num = dairy.recipe_num AND dairy.ingredient IN ('milk', 'cheese')
WHERE meat.ingredient IN ('pork' , 'steak','chicken','veal')
AND dairy.recipe_num IS NULL
```

Alternatively you can use a more intuitive `NOT IN` query. However, this may not perform as well.

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipe_num
FROM recipe
WHERE ingredient IN ('pork' , 'steak','chicken','veal')
AND recipe_num NOT IN (SELECT recipe_num
                       FROM recipe
                       WHERE ingredient IN ('milk', 'cheese'))
```

Comment: Actually your 2nd solution performance (2 sec) is better than the 1st (4 sec), using the same logic on a table with over 600,000 records. In comparison the solution below takes 4 sec (removing JOIN a to b) and the 2 solutions above take 28 sec.

Comment: @MySQLnoob Generally speaking, a `NOT EXISTS` query will outperform both of the above, and the `HAVING` version would likely outperform all  of them.

Answer (score 0):

While probably futile, the last part of this problem has been left as an exercise for the reader...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM recipe a 
  JOIN recipe b 
    ON b.recipe_num = a.recipe_num 
  LEFT 
  JOIN recipe c 
    ON c.recipe_num = a.recipe_num 
   AND c.ingredient IN ('milk','cream') 
 WHERE a.ingredient IN ('pork','steak','veal');
```

Comment: Yep. Futile. As I said.

Comment: I do see the answer is to add 'AND c. IS NULL' to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of `recipe_num` that meet your criteria, you don't need to `JOIN` at all, you can just use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT recipe_num
FROM recipe
GROUP BY recipe_num
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ingredient IN ('pork' , 'steak','chicken','veal') THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN ingredient IN ('milk' , 'cheese') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Likewise you can accomplish the same with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipe_num
FROM recipe a
WHERE a.ingredient IN ('pork','steak','chicken','veal')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT recipe_num
                  FROM recipe b
                  WHERE b.ingredient IN ('milk','cream')
                    AND a.recipe_num = b.recipe_num)
```